# PagedList ViewModel Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to implement pagedlist with a ViewModel in asp.net MVC.

Say I have the following PagedClientViewModel:

```
public class PagedClientViewModel
{
    public PagedList.IPagedList<ClientViewModel> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class ClientViewModel
{
    public string ClientNumber { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }       
}
```

My view will reference the model as follows:

```
@model PagedClientViewModel
```

and the action method looks something like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        var pageNumber = page ?? 1;

        var clients = GetAllClients();

        var onePageOfClients = clients.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25);

        PagedClientViewModel model = new PagedClientViewModel();

        var clientViewModels = new List<ClientViewModel>();

        foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            ClientViewModel clientVM = new ClientViewModel
            {
                ClientName = client.CLIENTNAME,
                ClientNumber = client.CLIENTNO,         
            };
            clientViewModels.Add(clientVM);
        }                    

        model.Clients = //how do I add the clientViewModels to the PagedList<ClientViewModel>?

        return View(model);
    }
```

I don't  want to iterate the entire list of client records from the database when creating the viewmodels - am I overcomplicating things by having a viewmodel that contains a pagedlist? I don't want to use ViewBag!

What should my ViewModel look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the call to retrieve your data to include a page parameter and do the filtering at the database.  This way you are only returning the data you need from the database.

```
var clients = GetClients(page);
```

Also, if you don't want to loop over your returned clients (which it doesn't seem like you need to here), just set the returned list directly to your ViewModel.  Something like this would work.  Make sure you update your ViewModel so `model.Clients` is typed appropriately.

```
var clients = GetClients(page);

model.Clients = clients;
```

Answer (score 3):

Got this to work quite nicely by using a combination of the answers:

```
    public ActionResult Index(PagedClientViewModel model)
    {
        var pageIndex = model.Page ?? 1;
        var clients = from client in GetAllClients() orderby client.CLIENTNUMBER
                      select new ClientViewModel
                          {
                              ClientName = client.CLIENTNAME,
                              ClientNumber = client.CLIENTNO

                          };        

        model.Clients = clients.ToPagedList(pageIndex, 25);

        return View(model);
    }


public class PagedClientViewModel
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public PagedList.IPagedList<ClientViewModel> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class ClientViewModel
{
    public string ClientNumber { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simplify it to sth like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ClientViewModel> Clients { get; set; }
```

and

```
model.Clients = from client in GetAllClients().Skip(pageNumber * PageSize).Take(PageSize)
                       select new ClientViewModel
                       {
                           ClientName = client.CLIENTNAME,
                           ClientNumber = client.CLIENTNO,  
                       };
```